# C# bitwise XOR (^) compared to Java bitwise XOR (^)

Tags: java, c#

I'm trying to convert some java code to C# and it's been working flawlessly so far but I've encountered an issue with the ^ operator. In C# `Console.WriteLine(127 ^ 0xffffffff);` prints 4294967168 whereas in Java `System.out.println(127 ^ 0xffffffff);` prints -128. I've been looking around to see if there is something else that I need to use instead but I haven't come across anything.

Comment: Forgot to add, I need it to print -128.

Comment: In Java, the operands are promoted to type `int`, and the result is an `int`.  In C# the operands are promoted to `uint`, and the result is a `uint`.  Appropriate casting should take care of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# supports *signed* as well as *unsigned* integers (Java supports *signed* ones only):

```
  unchecked {
    // you want signed int
    int result = (int) (127 ^ 0xffffffff);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
```

Comment: The real problem being that 0xffffffff cannot be represented as a positive number in a signed int, which then causes it to be interpreted as an unsigned int. `0xff` would be interpreted as an int and not unsigned int.

Comment: Ah! Silly me. Thank you very much! I'll select this as the answer when it lets me in around 6 minutes.